# Parse Json Array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to jQuery and Java script. I need to parse a JSON file that has arrays, I use this code:

```
$.getJSON('mat.json', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    });

    $('<ul/>', {'class': 'my-new-list', html: items.join('')}).appendTo('body');
});
```

For this JSON file:

```
{
    "@file_name": "materials",
    "materials": [{
        "@site_name_English": "N/A",
        "@site_name_Spanish": "N/A",
        "@site_number": "1",
        "zoom": [{
            "@zoom_name_English": "Main Reservoir",
            "@zoom_name_Spanish": "Depósito principal",
            "@zoom_number": "1",
            "icon": [
                {
                    "@icon_name": "Info Icon 1",
                    "@icon_pin": "1"
                },
                {
                    "@icon_name": "Info Icon 2",
                    "@icon_pin": "2"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

But my result is:

```
materials
[object Object]
```

How can I change my code so I will get the objects also when the loop meets them?

Comment: What properties of your JSON objects do you want to see in your `li` id and content, respectively?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to provide a jsFiddle ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) 
{
    if(typeof val === 'object') {
         $.each(val, function(keys, value) 
         {
         items.push('<li id="' + keys + '">' + value + '</li>'); 
         }
    } else {
       items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    }
});
```

You need to check that value is object or not.

**EDITED:**

```
function checkObj(key, val, items){
   if(typeof val === 'object') {
         $.each(val, function(keys, value) 
             {
            if(typeof value === 'object') {
                checkObj(keys, value, items);  
            } else {
               items.push('<li id="' + keys + '">' + value + '</li>'); 
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

And in the $.each function use this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) 
{
    if(typeof val === 'object') {
         checkObj(key, val, items);
    } else {
       items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
    }
});
```

Comment: @DanM you need to create a function that will be recursive function to read such JSON data. Give me time I will create that for you.

Answer (score 0):

The program shows how to read json and store data into textbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON("Test.json",function(data){

         $.each(data,function(key,value){
             alert(data[key].attrib1name);
             alert(data[key].attrib2name); 
             $('input').val(data[key].enterpriseName);
             activities=data[key].activities;
             console.log(value);
         });
     });    


});
```